# Вернуться назад с помощью php + #якорная ссылка

Tags: php

Как вернуться назад с добавлением якорный ссылки.
Есть код возвращающий назад пользователя:

```
<?php
   header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 exit;
?>
```

Как добавить к предыдущей странице якорную ссылку #link
Чтобы получился следующий адрес: `http://example.com/#link`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
   header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'/#link');
 exit;
?>
```